# Can I check a laptop with an un-removable laptop battery into my checked in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, prohibited-items, batteries

My HP laptop has a battery which cannot be removed.  It is a massive heavy thing, and I understand that it's unwise to check it in, but I wish to anyway at my own risk.  It's an international flight with no stopover (direct 3hr flight).

Am I still allowed to check in my laptop battery considering it cannot be removed?  And I'm also confused, if a powerbank can't be checked in as it is a lithium ion battery, then why can laptop batteries inside a laptop be checked in?

Thanks!

Comment: The biggest risk with Li-ion batteries are punctures and short-circuits. Inside a laptop the battery is fairly well protected against both, but a power-bank has pins that, when short-circuited, would pull energy from the battery, making it more risky.

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/passenger_info/media/Airline_passengers_and_batteries.pdf

Comment: You could as well throw it away, and buy a new one after arrival. Chances are it _will_ be stolen, and you get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can. But make sure the laptop is completely switched off. (Ie. Not just in sleep mode)

Lufthansa mentions on its website:

> Portable electronic devices containing lithium-metal or lithium-ion
> cells or batteries, e.g. watches, calculators, cameras, mobile phones,
> **laptop computers**, camcorders, etc., when these are intended for
> personal sue.
>
> Checked baggage: Yes (up to 100 Wh or 2 g) / No (100–160 Wh or 2–8 g)
>
> Carry-on baggage: Yes
>
> Carrier’s approval required: No (up to 100 Wh or 2 g) / Yes (100–160 Wh or 2–8 g)

https://www.lufthansa.com/ch/en/information-about-dangerous-goods#Batteries

It is unlikely that your laptop has more than 100Wh stored in its battery (typical is about 50Wh)

Comment: Of course, this is only for Lufthansa.  If you're flying with a different airline, then you should check that airline's rules, as they could be different.

Comment: Rules are the same with KLM: https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/restricted_article/index.htm#p3 do i assume this is pretty much the standard in the industry: <100Wh, integrated in a device, no problem.